# data freshness policy in REST APIs

Tags: rest, policy

It's possible that a backend system is under heavy load,accumulates a backlog in terms of unprocessed data. This causes an outdated data in a database. 
What is the recommended practice to indicate it in the API returning this outdated data?
Thank you,
Vlad

Comment: You can probably send a last-modified header or an etag. But I don't fully understand the question, can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure. If a back-end for some reason has failed or is in out of service this causes the data in databases to be outdated. For example : the number of conversions will outdated and only when the back-end will return to serve it will close the gap. The question is how to know in the client side that is valid up to ...

Comment: By HTTP the client always can have stale data, you cannot avoid that. That's why some ppl use eventual consistency model on server side and add timestamps to the responses. If you cannot send back an immediate answer to a client about a writing process, then you can send a 202 - accepted header. But maybe I still don't get the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for the backend to know which updates are pending and inform the client about it.

If there is a backlog of requests being processed is because the backend can't serve them. So the backend is unaware of which request are pending.

Another supposition is that the backend processes update requests but postpones service of data reads which are delegated to a cache. Then the cache could inform the client that the data it's reading MAY be outdated, but can't give precise information without consulting the backend which seems what you can't do or don't want to do.